# How to hide particular SharePoint post use checkbox?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery

How can I hide my particular post in Sharpoint blogs, if   I use checkbox field in post list by using javascript or jquery ? please if  some have an idea ,please  help me to resolve  it.  will great appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the page of the blog site and customise the view of the blog posts to filter by your checkbox column.  No jQuery needed.

Comment: Thank You Dave,I have already been using this method, simply had other demands to resolve that. I was doing exactly with this method, and determine  my checkbox is checked , then all the fields to edid disabled with jquer.

Answer (score 0):

Change Approval Status Approved to Pending or Reject, then the post visible only Author of the post.